# how to bring a horizontal listview item when touched to the first position?

Tags: android

I have a horizontallistview.When i click on the second item of listview it should come to first positio, each element of the listview should come to the first position.thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0):

Use `setSelectionAfterHeaderView()` method and pass 0 as the distance from the header.